# How to get the code returned by Cognito Hosted UI Autentication in Django?

Tags: python, django, authentication, amazon-cognito

I want to implement the Cognito Hosted UI for some users in my Django application.
I have successfully been able to redirect the users to the desired url for authentication using the following:

`return redirect(https://....amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=....redirect_uri=localhost)`.

I am able to successfully authenticate and redirect back to my `localhost` where the url in the browser is `localhost/?code=xyz`. I do not understand how I can retrieve this code `xyz` back in python to perform next steps? I see that in the Django Terminal that it reads the required code. This is what the terminal shows:

`[04/May/2022 16:08:15] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 0`

`[04/May/2022 12:09:04] "GET /?code=xyz HTTP/1.1" 200 8737`

I just do not know how to get this code `xyz` in my views.py so that I can continue the login. I tried variations of `request.GET` that did not work.

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out 5 days later (what 5 days of not looking at your code can do!)

`request.GET.get(‘code’)` gives back the 'xyz' that shows up in the url in the browser.